# A built-in way to make Vim open a new buffer with file?

Tags: buffers

Is there a built-in way to make Vim open a new buffer with file?

I want open a **file**. `:enew` doesn't take any arguments and opens a **blank** buffer.
`:edit` closes my existing buffer.

---

Related (about `:enew`):

- [How do I open a new buffer without opening it in a split?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/8215/how-do-i-open-a-new-buffer-without-opening-it-in-a-split)
- [How do you open a new buffer in the current window?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/2768/how-do-you-open-a-new-buffer-in-the-current-window)

Answer (score 43, accepted):

I think you might be misunderstanding what you're seeing happen.  `:edit` does not close your current buffer.  It just *replaces* it in the current *window*.  If you type `:buffers` your previous buffer should still be listed.  It is still open and in Vim's memory.  The only way to make them go away is to run `:bd` or `:bw` (or `:q` of course).

So, to answer your question: `:e newfile.txt`

Your previous buffer is now the `alternate file` to the current buffer (`:help alternate-file`).  You can switch back to it using `ctrl-^` or `ctrl-6`.

There are commands similar to `:edit`

- `:split` - horizontal split
- `:vsplit` - vertical split

Both of these commands (shortened `:sp` and `:vs` respectively) take an optional `file` argument like `:edit` does.  So, if you wanted to vertically split and create a new file in one command, you would type: `:vs newfile.txt`

Give `:help edit-intro` a read to get an idea of how Vim handles files, and `:help windows-intro` to read up on windows, buffers, and tabs.

Answer (score 11):

I can accomplish the behavior using this, but it's kinda annoying to have to do a few extra keystrokes:

```
:enew         " shorthand: ene
:edit <file>  " shorthand: e

" Shorthand to do both
:ene|e <file>
```

Comment: @JairLopez This is opens a new split for me. From `:h new`: "This behaves like a ":split" first, and then an ":enew" command."